# How to auto fill textbox with data have selected when click edit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

how do I display data in the textbox automatically when I click on the edit button, I want to display data from the database using jquery chosen like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiMHU.png)
, sorry if my question is unclear, if anyone is unable to ask me, please help

This is my code

```
<?php
$main_controll = new App_UserManagement_Control_UserManagement();
$data_from_ctr = $main_controll->edit();
echo json_encode( $data_from_ctr);
?>

<tr class="odd">
            <td width="150"><strong>Account Access</strong></td>
            <td width="10">:</td>
            <td colspan="2">
            <select id="acctAccessed" name="acctAccessed[]" multiple="multiple" class="chosen-select" style="width:350px;" data-placeholder="Select account">
            <?php foreach ($data_from_ctr['rek'] as $data) :?>
            <option <?php if ($data['selected'] == "1"){ ?> selected= "" <? } ?> value="<?php echo $data['idRek'];?>"><?php echo $data['idRek'];?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            <input id="chkall" type="checkbox" >Select All</input>
        </td>

<script type="text/javascript">
      $("#acctAccessed").chosen();
</script>
```

but my error like this, I don't get data for account access
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKxtb.png)

Comment: Have you tried using `placeholder=` instead of `data-placeholder=`?

Comment: no I don't have trying, I will trying now @Arkin Solomon

Comment: I have tried same to for result @ArkinSolomon

Answer (score 0):

Can you post $data_from_ctr as , the above mentioned code by you is working.

Comment: yes is working the data is show like list dropdown, but no show like selected @shreyanshu agarwal